# How can I remove unchecked and deleted songs in iTunes from my iPhone?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, music, library

Music which I've deleted from library and/or unchecked still appears on iPhone 4 and plays with checked music even after syncing.  How can I delete music from iPhone so it does not play any more?

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes, you can select the music to sync by track, playlist, artist, album, genre.

In order to delete a track from the iPhone, it shouldn't match *any* of the aforementioned criteria. Maybe the tracks are included in some smart playlist which is synced (Recent?).